# Implementing easing where angles are involved, how?

Tags: javascript, html, easing

I am trying to add some 'juice' to a game I am working on in Javascript. I looked up some easing functions and applied them in the following way.

```
//this.x += (this.speed * this.game.clockTick) * Math.sin(this.angle);
        //this.y += (this.speed * this.game.clockTick) * Math.cos(this.angle);

        this.x = Easing.easeInCubic(this.time, this.startX, this.targetX, 2); //* Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y = Easing.easeInCubic(this.time, this.startY, this.targetY, 2); //* Math.sin(this.angle);
```

The code I remarked out at the top is how I was working originally, but I now want to apply this easing function to give my missiles a nicer looking launch! :)

Can anybody help me out here?

I guess it might of been helpful if I also included the easing function itself:

```
easeInCubic: function(time,start,end,duration) {
        return end*(time/=duration)*time*time+start;
    }
```

Okay, so rather than applying the easing to start and end position, I was able to get something closer to what I was trying to achieve by applying the easing to the speed on the projectile.

```
this.x += Easing.easeInCubic(this.time, 0, this.speed, 3) * Math.sin(this.angle); 
        this.y += Easing.easeInCubic(this.time, 0, this.speed, 3) * Math.cos(this.angle);
```

Comment: I assume `angle` and `speed` don't change over time? Or do they? Because if they do change, you cannot use these easing-equations, then you'd have to deal with velocity.

Comment: Angle does not change, I just want the projectile to move in a straight line at the given angle with. Speed I guess will become redundant if I can get this working,